# Using a string value to infer a deeper dependent type in the same object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

## Background

I'm trying to create a method that accepts a map of Component class types, and then a map of InstanceInfo objects that reference the Components by their string name. Each Component class type contains a class type specific generic `PropsType` which is a map of various property values unique to the class type. I'd like my InstanceInfo objects, based on the string name of the Component passed in in the `type` property, to infer properly the PropsType paired with the reference Component.

Here's an example of the method being called:

```
const config = createConfig({
  components: {
    ComponentA,
    ComponentB
  }
}, {
  instances: {
    ComponentAInstance1: { // InstanceInfo
      componentName: 'ComponentA',
      props: {
        componentAProp1: 123,
        componentAProp2: 'abc'
      }
    },
    ComponentBInstance1: { // InstanceInfo
      componentName: 'ComponentB',
      props: {
        componentBProp1: true,
        componentBProp2: false
      }
    },
  },
});
```

Both `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` in the example extend the anonymous class returned by this function:

```
function createComponentType<
  PropsType = undefined
>() {
  return class {
    constructor(public props: PropsType) {
      // Nothing
    }
    static __type_PropsType: PropsType; // Phantom type
  }
}
```

This function places a "phantom type" for PropsType into a static property so that it can be referenced via [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) later.

Here are the two components being created with their own unique set of PropsTypes:

```
type ComponentAProps = {
  componentAProp1: number,
  componentAProp2: string
}

class ComponentA extends createComponentType<ComponentAProps>() {}

type ComponentBProps = {
  componentBProp1: boolean,
  componentBProp2: boolean
}

class ComponentB extends createComponentType<ComponentBProps>() {}
```

To define our InstanceInfo, we assume, via generic parameters, we have the actual type of the Components map, as well as the specific string name of the Component, which is constrained to the keys of the Components Map:

```
interface InstanceInfo<
  Components extends Record<string, TypeOfComponent>,
  ComponentName extends keyof Components
> {
  componentName: ComponentName,
  props: Components[ComponentName] extends TypeOfComponent ? Components[ComponentName]['__type_PropsType'] : never
};
```

Here we restrict the `componentName` property to be of the valid `ComponentName`. For the `props` we use a indexed access types and conditional type to check that the Component referenced by the name ComponentName is truly a TypeOfComponent. If so, we use the phantom PropsType as the type expected for `props`. If it's not, then we know we've got an invalid Component reference going on, so `never` is returned from the condition.

The structures for the ComponentConfig and InstanceConfig are fairly straightforward:

```
/**
 * Represents a configured set of Components
 */
interface ComponentConfig<
  Components extends Record<string, TypeOfComponent>
> {
  components: Components,
}

/**
 * Represents a configured set of Instances
 */
interface InstanceConfig<
  Components extends Record<string, TypeOfComponent>,
  Instances extends Record<string, InstanceInfo<Components, keyof Components>>
> {
  instances: Instances,
}
```

The generics in both cases here are used to facilitate generic type inference from the `createConfig()` method.

To make it so that `createConfig()` returns a single object containing both the component map and instance map, we create a CombinedConfig interface:

```
interface CombinedConfig<
  Components extends Record<string, TypeOfComponent>,
  Instances extends Record<string, InstanceInfo<Components, keyof Components>>,
> extends ComponentConfig<Components>, InstanceConfig<Components, Instances> {}
```

Finally, here's the `createConfig()` method, which works fairly straightforwardly:

```
function createConfig<
  Components extends Record<string, TypeOfComponent>,
  Instances extends Record<string, InstanceInfo<Components, keyof Components>>
>(componentConfig: ComponentConfig<Components>, instanceConfig: InstanceConfig<Components, Instances>): CombinedConfig<Components, Instances> {
  return {
    ...componentConfig,
    ...instanceConfig
  };
}
```

## Problem

I have this *almost* working the way I want. However there is a huge gotcha to it that I'm having trouble rectifying.

The typing is being enforced to an extent, but in a bad way it is too permissive. The first blob of code example above works fine. TypeScript enforces both that the `componentName` and `props` are at least independently valid. However, this means that the `componentName` and `props` can vary in unintended ways:

- `componentName` may be ComponentA, but `props` may be ComponentBProps
- `componentName` may be ComponentB, but `props` may be ComponentAProps (the opposite)

I'm looking for the `componentName` to **determine** what the type of `props` should be. i.e. The `props` type should be dependent on what string is used for `componentName`.

```
const config = createConfig({
  components: {
    ComponentA,
    ComponentB
  }
}, {
  instances: {
    ComponentAInstance2: {
      componentName: 'ComponentA',
      // Bad!!! I want an error because using ComponentBProps with ComponentA!
      props: {
        componentBProp1: false,
        componentBProp2: true
      }
    },
    ComponentBInstance2: {
      componentName: 'ComponentB',
      // Bad!!! I want an error because using ComponentAProps with ComponentB!
      props: {
        componentAProp1: 123,
        componentAProp2: 'abc'
      }
    },
  },
});
```

I think I kind of understand the basic issue. Going back to InstanceConfig:

```
interface InstanceConfig<
  Components extends Record<string, TypeOfComponent>,
  Instances extends Record<string, InstanceInfo<Components, keyof Components>>
> {
  instances: Instances,
}
```

`Instances` extends `Record<string, InstanceInfo<Components, keyof Components>>` and that ultimately will expand to is something like this:

```
Record<
  string,
  {
    componentName: 'ComponentA' | 'ComponentB',
    props: Components['ComponentA']['__type_PropsType'] | Components['ComponentB']['__type_PropsType']
  }
>
```

This explains the acceptance of any combination of componentNames and props types.

However, I need a way to somehow tell TypeScript to expand that into something like this instead so there is a tight discriminated union:

```
Record<
  string,
  {
    componentName: 'ComponentA',
    props: Components['ComponentA']['__type_PropsType']
  } |
  {
    componentName: 'ComponentB',
    props: Components['ComponentB']['__type_PropsType']
  }
>
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to achieve this in anyway with TypeScript currently? Or am I really stretching what's possible with it too far?

## Full Code

```
//
// Set up
// Create a class factory function for a generic class containing a generic PropsType
//
type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

interface Component<PropsType> {
  props: PropsType;
}

type TypeOfComponent<
  PropsType = unknown
> = Constructor<Component<PropsType>> & { __type_PropsType: PropsType };

function createComponentType<
  PropsType = undefined
>() {
  return class {
    constructor(public props: PropsType) {
      // Nothing
    }
    static __type_PropsType: PropsType; // Phantom type
  }
}


//
// Create components
//
type ComponentAProps = {
  componentAProp1: number,
  componentAProp2: string
}

class ComponentA extends createComponentType<ComponentAProps>() {}

type ComponentBProps = {
  componentBProp1: boolean,
  componentBProp2: boolean
}

class ComponentB extends createComponentType<ComponentBProps>() {}

//
// Set up our essential types
//

/**
 * Represents Instance Data of a Component referenced by its string name
 */
interface InstanceInfo<
  Components extends Record<string, TypeOfComponent>,
  ComponentName extends keyof Components
> {
  componentName: ComponentName,
  /**
   * This type extracts the __type_PropsType from the passed in component
   */
  props: Components[ComponentName] extends TypeOfComponent ? Components[ComponentName]['__type_PropsType'] : never
};

/**
 * Represents a configured set of Components
 */
interface ComponentConfig<
  Components extends Record<string, TypeOfComponent>
> {
  components: Components,
}

/**
 * Represents a configured set of Instances
 */
interface InstanceConfig<
  Components extends Record<string, TypeOfComponent>,
  Instances extends Record<string, InstanceInfo<Components, keyof Components>>
> {
  instances: Instances,
}

/**
 * Represents the combined Component and Instance config returned by createConfig
 */
interface CombinedConfig<
  Components extends Record<string, TypeOfComponent>,
  Instances extends Record<string, InstanceInfo<Components, keyof Components>>,
> extends ComponentConfig<Components>, InstanceConfig<Components, Instances> {}

/**
 * Creates configuration of both components and their instance data, first inferring the Components type from componentConfig, and using that to
 * inform how the Instances are to be formatted
 */
function createConfig<
  Components extends Record<string, TypeOfComponent>,
  Instances extends Record<string, InstanceInfo<Components, keyof Components>>
>(componentConfig: ComponentConfig<Components>, instanceConfig: InstanceConfig<Components, Instances>): CombinedConfig<Components, Instances> {
  return {
    ...componentConfig,
    ...instanceConfig
  };
}

const config = createConfig({
  components: {
    ComponentA,
    ComponentB
  }
}, {
  instances: {
    ComponentAInstance1: {
      componentName: 'ComponentA',
      // Good!
      props: {
        componentAProp1: 123,
        componentAProp2: 'abc'
      }
    },
    ComponentBInstance1: {
      componentName: 'ComponentB',
      // Good!
      props: {
        componentBProp1: true,
        componentBProp2: false
      }
    },
    ComponentAInstance2: {
      componentName: 'ComponentA',
      // Bad!!! I want an error because using ComponentBProps with ComponentA!
      props: {
        componentBProp1: false,
        componentBProp2: true
      }
    },
    ComponentBInstance2: {
      componentName: 'ComponentB',
      // Bad!!! I want an error because using ComponentAProps with ComponentB!
      props: {
        componentAProp1: 123,
        componentAProp2: 'abc'
      }
    },
  },
});

console.log(config.instances.ComponentAInstance1.props.componentAProp1); // Good
console.log(config.instances.ComponentAInstance1.props.componentAProp2); // Good

console.log(config.instances.ComponentBInstance1.props.componentBProp1); // Good
console.log(config.instances.ComponentBInstance1.props.componentBProp2); // Good

console.log(config.instances.ComponentAInstance2.props.componentBProp1); // I don't want this to be allowed
console.log(config.instances.ComponentAInstance2.props.componentBProp2); // I don't want this to be allowed

console.log(config.instances.ComponentBInstance2.props.componentAProp1); // I don't want this to be allowed
console.log(config.instances.ComponentBInstance2.props.componentAProp2); // I don't want this to be allowed
```

TypeScript version: 4.3 (see Playground for compiler options)
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTCwCgQAgZQUwC5QK4AcLQMICc4EME4o8oBjAGzwGcqoAzPUhAe2wE97kA7JgS2a71WxKAHM4XONl6kylGmQEI8vLqtEjxk6bIAK2ZqioAVNqjgYw4BGaKYBVBNmRNWAHmNQAvFADeAXwA+byhJAHcoAAoAOli8bFEqAC5iLjYAbQBdAEpvYOMAbggIVUJsBlI7ZgBbVAEJBDd9QxNbYN8IKChUAyMU5qNTcyLwf2LrWyghuAB5Onta+q5GzqgB1vMQ7gBrLmYwrghgn3suR2dXbDcFusllpt6NuEDggDI-KAB9T5tzT-Xpv1HtMoP4RhA6Nw+AIyLgCHAbksENM3KsAZMfNwACZwOiqOBYo6RXIdcBdXAIZDYQQUai0UldLqkBxOFwsbCRVDIABG5Bk3UeQJa0xJq0ZUGgADlmAgABbqMWgxWOAj876-OD-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-nRcx6tyqM4AANykbdwUgZy2Ng+DcCQsyRGZLg8VEKlYqQpBjNEqCOOWLjGCqUyEFOKbhI04qxOPCtaCk1hZPkxTCvmYrAiOPxLI25JyqRKgFyfAaoGguCENG2iSAmqaZsouaPwI3iMMqYD3uWspuKgUHTUqLbeFEHbHrdfb8qG6TTqcdRzuUy6NrU1Y4cw9G9Mxk65JxhjFJJyoBKE0TFIMoyCNEl4bqDVQ+PBlI6cQl7xmAN6PuGxDkIiohk25fFKKI01KP5xRJqR4jECpSRKO5Dhq3PRHRCWkoVvKNaTJlzX9ZR0S8vJ46ZKp6QaaU8wisJxz+bJw6Kfts7YfQ+G4AZ649uZwyFr2l4F2CXSvcbS32dp-3MPjkO-Z5xD2leyDBsdeEqwEf7vIQfhBGMqc5QSiWFcl3hsDipPKigLFcMUvFsEcevSOwR2ND81GJa7ULzRHJF9cU6vkCodQIoIC1mCgzvWHC2V9kltOwcQ4hcDn9ciEE7BqgIQhCTYqxIR4YuYV1+FLdWa2Y8kuAsYd3HndmAnRyJxcPZtr27exnuid05ByZlAFm4d7oc3AK2Eebp9bpQ2inSBiluYb3gevAOSCKpAI3lQQI2QEHmwJFgp6OCA54NuouCkGtKHiliNEWBDQx6KnoagzBBckZWhGDuCaHc-qqx8NfWsHDRCRGHHtFIQZdobV9I5aRo4+xWm3IpLmDdEKSMVI2X0-NIy0PFJXZYNUUj1S0fVORjJoAAHFpxYgAISKhSoKPR+iDFNgGLo8MaYADM5jxSMOWM2VAa56p4G5KQeqDilSLi6P4cxB4dEaOiYyfxCAjFQBMcVPsZjIlWJsfYpJji0rOP0Sku8ujWRwF8ckzJ6YUgMHIEhSJ1pxSxM0cVbRai1xSOqRtNJGSZHZIKYaKAfY8B2NsbY2GUAwimiQKaYs3dhBxlIHgSeRBJ7TwPAGMINFZT9wCfklxqU+jFL8TUic9B-xISqUyc5q4UgVKaYqVpST4mdMSS4lJfSDyDJcdAUZ4zJkoWmbM1ICyDB12WaspCKAp4MX2W4x40zdkIr7Ic-RxyHrdLOTI9xKRPE+Mibc3FvRgmhPCU8pJLyYkvWyH1Xhm5ojkGYKI-hohohsNJtELROjoiYoYe09xdLhnWOYCfBls4mUssiGyjlaiqDcvaby-lKTAlpmFbksV4wJVwClaykRcr04KreencMfLHgCo2mUjVRpRXiocIy5l+qVbss5eDRVVrlUWtKemG1UA7XaodZKp1MqDVusQh60cHT05pnNS0S1CihUGmgMCrEAh6pIBmcsCKvAPLMF3sQcgzKwgEjzEG3VIbZXhuNUqzpcajAJuXL65NRpU3pszaCuUuad5xkLcW0tuZdzlr1aGl1hrcGRuXPzWNKrBURj9W2rgGaQXZq7Xmgt-5+32rOI66VVb5WTtvNO+tCrVXNuGYu5dWakBrp7UQTd+wCRAA)

Answer (score 1):

The core problem you are facing is as you have already mentioned the lack of discriminated union. Now it is possible by creating an object and referencing the object  (copied from @jcalz)

```js
type ComponentInstance<
  Components extends Record<string, TypeOfComponent>,
> = {
    [K in keyof Components]: {
      componentName: K,
      props: Components[K]["__type_PropsType"]
    }
  }[keyof Components];
```

Then we can simply update your types to be:

```js
interface ComponentConfig<
  Components extends Record<string, TypeOfComponent>
> {
  components: Components,
}

interface InstanceConfig<
  Components extends Record<string, TypeOfComponent>,
> {
  instances: Record<string, ComponentInstance<Components>>,
}
```

Now you can actually just plug this into the `createConfig` function as shown:

```js
function createConfig2<
  Components extends Record<string, TypeOfComponent>,
>(componentConfig: ComponentConfig<Components>, instanceConfig: InstanceConfig<Components>) {
  return {
    ...componentConfig,
    ...instanceConfig
  };
}
```

But the problem is that the return value is not based on the arguments that you passed. (resulting in question 2). This is because the type output is:

```js
type Config: {
    instances: Record<string, ComponentInstance<{
        ComponentA: typeof ComponentA;
        ComponentB: typeof ComponentB;
    }>>;
    components: {
        ComponentA: typeof ComponentA;
        ComponentB: typeof ComponentB;
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks @zecuria! It looks like I was able to get everything to work the way I wanted just by applying the @jcalz copied "trick" you referred to in your first code blurb to the InstanceInfo type. Happy to accept the answer if you update it as such.

Comment: Updated the answer hope that helps

Comment: I mean that literally using just that one trick was all I needed to do. The answer here still changes other aspects of my code. I'd send you an updated playground link, but it won't fit in a comment and there doesn't seem to be a way to DM you over stackoverflow.